# Set titlebar css for specific dialog in jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I created jqueryui dialog **$('#mydialog').dialog({...});**

I want to set titlebar attributes. I know I can do this with CSS and works fine:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
   font-size: 10pt;
}
```

What if I want to do it for a specific dialog? I have tried below but it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
#mydialog.ui-dialog-titlebar {
   font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7VW4V/

Basically add an id to the dialog widget (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-widget) as follows:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('widget').attr('id', 'dialogId');
```

Then the CSS is straightforward

```
#dialogId .ui-dialog-titlebar  {
    background:red;
}
```